# iOS 7 Update UI During NSURLConnection Async Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

After my UIViewController segues... inside the viewDidAppear I am making an asynchronous NSURLConnection call to retrieve some data. One of the pieces of data is a URL for an image that I will show the user on this new view.

I pass my method doing the NSURLConnection a block that I want to use as a callback after all the data is returned from the server; I call it in connectionDidFinishLoading.

Here is the block I am sending as my callback for connectionDidFinishLoading to call:

```
^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {

            if (success) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [loadingImageView startAnimating];
                    [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userSubmission.storageUri]]]];
                });

                NSLog(@"Is Main Thread: %ld", (long)[NSThread isMainThread]);
                userSubmission = [[Submission alloc] initWithDictionary:response];
                if (userSubmission.votes) {
                    _numberOfVotesSubmissions.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)userSubmission.votes];
                } else {
                    _numberOfVotesSubmissions.text = @"0";
                }
                _votesOrSubmissionsImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list_votes_icon"];


            } else {
                _numberOfVotesSubmissions.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long) _clue.submissions];
                _votesOrSubmissionsImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list_photo_icon"];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [loadingImageView stopAnimating];
            });
        }];
```

I put a break point at the point where I try to load the image and at the point where I try to stop the "loadingImageView" from animating and I NEVER see the UIActivityViewController.

I have a UIImageView that is 300x300 and I place my UIActivityViewController in the middle of it (via addSubView).

This work beautifully if I start the UIActivityViewController spinning inside of viewDidAppear, however, there's not always going to be a scenario where I'll have an image to show and in that case the default "no image found" image is what I want to present.

I assume my problem is that I am running the NSURLConnection call and the run loop wants to finish my block callback before it starts the other stuff.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are loading the image data on the main thread - that's bad. You also try to do a lot of UI work in the background. Try this:

```
^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [loadingImageView startAnimating];
            });

            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userSubmission.storageUri]];
            NSLog(@"Is Main Thread: %ld", (long)[NSThread isMainThread]);
            userSubmission = [[Submission alloc] initWithDictionary:response];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
                if (userSubmission.votes) {
                    _numberOfVotesSubmissions.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)userSubmission.votes];
                } else {
                    _numberOfVotesSubmissions.text = @"0";
                }
                _votesOrSubmissionsImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list_votes_icon"];
                [loadingImageView stopAnimating];
            });
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                _numberOfVotesSubmissions.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long) _clue.submissions];
                _votesOrSubmissionsImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list_photo_icon"];
            });
        }
    }];
```

Comment: I tried this... it didn't work... I know it has something to do with how I am making my calls... I took out all the "non image stuff" and i put a breakpoint at the "stopAnimating" and not only do I not she the "spinner", but I also don't see the image, yet. Is there some sort of "commit changes to the UI I need to call"?

Comment: Is this block being called on the main thread or a background thread? Is `loadingImageView` non-nil?

Comment: According to my debugger loadingImageView is not nil... I'm calling my method to load the data on the main thread (I believe)... I don't do any dispatch_async or performSelectoronThread or NSOPerationQueue stuff

Comment: If this block is called on the main thread then there is the problem. You need to ensure that the call to load the data from the URL is being done in the background.

Comment: Yep. And if the block is on the main thread, you don't need to wrap the other code to run on the main queue.

Comment: So... what was happening was i wasn't using the "async" methods of NSURLConnection that returns with the block... I was using the method that used the delegate methods... changing it worked like a charm... thanks!